# jwplayer start with nth video on playlist?

Tags: video, jwplayer

got a decent setup working with jwplayer and the playlists. One thing i can't track down is whether i can start with a certain video from the playlist? ie the 2nd or 3rd.
(I've found shuffle but that's not what i want and i need to keep the existing order...)

current working code...

```
jwplayer("placeholder1").setup({

                    autostart: true,
                    flashplayer: "/scripts/player/player.swf", 
                    playlist: [<?=rtrim($flashList, ',')?>], /* "playlist.position": "bottom", "playlist.size": 60, */
                    width:640,
                    height: 445,
                    controlbar: "bottom",
                    repeat: 'list' 

});
```

any help appreciated! Dc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is add one flashvar:

item: 4

to tell it to start on item 4 of the playlist

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12536/configuration-options#behavior

Comment: item: 4 will start it on the 5th item of the playlist (0 based array)

Comment: The link in this answer is no longer valid

Answer (score 0):

```
jwplayer().playlistItem(index)
```

https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-javascript-api-reference#section-jwplayer-playlist-item-index